# A2DP and Bluetooth issue upon reconnecting

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headset, a2dp, blueman

I have a pesky issue on **Ubuntu 16.04** with my bluetooth adapter and my **BT Headset** (**Bluedio**). When I first pair the device with my PC the headset does works fine and I can listen to everything with **A2DP Sink** (I can view it in Sound tab under System Settings). But when I disconnect or poweroff my headset, upon reconnecting I have problems: the device doesn't reconnect automatically (as it should do). Most of the time I can fix the issue removing the bluetooth device and pairing again, but this is really annoying. I just tried installing **blueman-applet** along with the default one but the issue remains the same. I tried searching on Google and here but I didn't find anything useful for me. The only error I can obtain is with blueman-applet and tells something about **A2DP_SINK** that can't connect.
I don't know if this is a bug or something similar, please let me know how should I proceed to find a fix or if I need to be more specific or give more details on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: A little workaround could be: run pavucontrol from the command line, select the configuration tab and then try changing the profile for your headphones and see if that updates for you. If it already says A2DP change it to OFF, disconnect the device in the bluetooth applet, then reconnect it. Then finally proceed to change the profile back to A2DP and it should work.

Comment: your suggestion works for me.  Any idea for a permanent fix?  Firing up pavucontrol and connecting/reconnecting almost takes as long as unpairing/pairing again.   I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 now but also had same issue on 16.04lts.

Comment: It seems that if I disconnect the headphones from Ubuntu (rather than simply switching them off) and then activate them in pavucontrol they still keep A2DP.